# Beginner issue regarding an array

Tags: arrays

Question:
Given is the array prices with 100 elements(prices[100]). The problem consists of two parts:
a. Find the highest price in the array (WITHOUT using the built-in SORT function)
b. Reduce that price by 10%

I'm currently taking COSC 1436 and I have this problem to solve for homework. I'm very new to arrays so if someone can tell me if my code solves my problem, I'd appreciate it. However, if my code doesn't solve my problem, then if you can point me in the right different to find resolve this I'd very much appreciate it.

```
Set max = a[0];
Set sum = 0;
for i = 1 to 100 by 1 do 
if a[i] > max then 
Set max = a[i];
endif
endfor
sum = sum + (max - (max/0.1))
print(sum);
```

Comment: the question does not mention to sum something and ` Reduce that price by 10%` that mean you have to calculate `max - max*0.1` or simplify `max*0.9`

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comment. `Reduce that price by 10%` that means you have to calculate `max - max*0.1` or simplify `max*0.9`

```
Set max = a[0];

for i = 1 to 100 by 1 do 
   if a[i] > max then 
      Set max = a[i];
   endif
endfor

Set price = max*0.9
print(price);
```

Comment: @invertdefault if it solve your question, don't forget to mark the correct answer